# How to investigate continuous cpu usage by a process on Windows

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, windows-services

My process on a users machine consumes 5-20% cpu continuously even when machine is idle. I cannot repro this issue on my end. So I am bit lost on how can I investigate this issue. Please note that 5-20% cpu consumption that I am talking about is not at machine level; but single process is taking that much cpu when it was taking nothing (~0) earlier. So most likely this is a regression. Here is what I have tried -

1. Reproducing on my end which was not successful.
2. Getting process dump from user. But it is snapshot in time and is not giving enough info about cpu usage over time. So cannot conclude what the problem is.

Any idea what data I can use to investigate this issue?

Comment: have you tried ProcMon? that's probably where I'd start.

Comment: What does your process do? With inky generic information we can only give generic suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Run Windows Tools, Resource Monitor.

Let it run for 15 minutes or so and see how your process is taking CPU.

CPU at idle will run 5% or a bit more and that is completely normal.

I posted a screen shot to assist you.

You can access the user's machine and run it there. Allow enough time to create a useful output.

Windows Tools, Performance Monitor and SysInternals Process Monitor may also prove useful, but more complex to use. They can collect datasets which may help you analyse.

[image: Windows Resource Monitor]

Comment: Process Monitor will give cpu consumption for the entire machine right? 5% cpu consumption at machine level is normal, I agree, but in my case, my process alone is taking 5-20% continuously. It was not the case earlier. I have updated the original question a bit.

Comment: You can evaluate your process alongside other process related to it. That should help. You can also use Performance Monitor to collect a dataset but that is much more complex to use.   SysInternals Process Monitor may also be helpful but it too produces a lot of data.